# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns1:Client.AUTH_1] Authentication Failed

Tags: php, soap

In my wsdl file I have a user authentication block:

```
<!-- User authentication -->

    <element name="UserAuthentication">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="iId" type="xsd:int" />
                <element name="sPassword" type="xsd:string" />
                <element name="sType" type="api:UserType" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
```

I'm trying to instantiate a SOAP call like thus:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.example.com/v2/example?wsdl",
    array(
         'iId' => 123456, 
         'sPassword' => 'fhfhfhfhfhfhfh46464dtdts64iyiyi', 
         'sType' => 'ghfh57477gghdkskdk68585jghhddhdghds'));
```

with real values provided. The script reports:

```
SoapFault exception: [ns1:Client.AUTH_1] Authentication Failed in
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this by any change the affiliatewindow API? And what is the message from the API? Just another wild guess: missing headers?

Comment: @Gal - Yes, most profound

Comment: @Max, it is indeed. I didn't get the job ;).

Comment: Sorry mate, better luck next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing your request data inside **options** for `SoapClient` instead of as parameters to the soap call.

The code should look like this (assuming the soap call is `Authenticate`):

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.example.com/v2/example?wsdl");

$response = $client->Authenticate(Array(
   'iId' => 123456, 
   'sPassword' => 'fhfhfhfhfhfhfh46464dtdts64iyiyi', 
   'sType' => 'ghfh57477gghdkskdk68585jghhddhdghds'));
   ));
```

And, in any event, you should use `try..catch` to prevent exceptions from crashing your code.

```
try
{
   // code here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   // error handling goes here
   die("Error: ". $e->getMessage()."\n");
}
```

Comment: Some good comments from Max and poncha, thanks. Who should get the bounty?

Comment: I may or may not have got past this point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173191/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-client-soap-error-encoding-object

Answer (score 1):

Without the full WSDL specification it's hard to tell where the issue is. But my guess is you're looking at the specs. wrong. Probably those are **headers** that need to be sent, not actual methods that need to be called.

So try with something like this:

```
// SOAP client options
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace'        => true,
);

// initialise the SOAP client
$apiURL = 'http://api.example.com/v2/example?wsdl';
$namespace = 'http://api.example.com/v2/example?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($apiURL, $options);

// the SOAP headers
$headers = array();

$ua = array(
    'iId' => 123456,
    'sPassword' => 'fhfhfhfhfhfhfh46464dtdts64iyiyi', 
    'sType' => 'ghfh57477gghdkskdk68585jghhddhdghds',
);

$headers[] = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'UserAuthentication', $ua);

// we could add multiple headers if needed

$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

// call the API function
$response = $client->__soapCall("whateverYourTryingToCall", null);
```