# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'iId' property

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to query a SOAP API and am receiving the above error. If I was to take a guess I'd say it's relative to this snippet from my wsdl file...

```
<!-- User authentication -->

    <element name="UserAuthentication">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="iId" type="xsd:int" />
                <element name="sPassword" type="xsd:string" />
                <element name="sType" type="api:UserType" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
```

In `getSoapResults()` - do you have any idea where I'd put 'iId'? In fact, I'm not even sure what 'iId' relates to at this point, other than an integer of course.

```
<?php
public function getSoapResults() {

    $this->client = new SoapClient("http://api.example.com/v2/Example?wsdl");
    $this->header = new SoapHeader('http://api.example.com/', 'sAPIKey', '*************');
    $this->client->__setSoapHeaders($this->header);

    $oRefineByDefinition = new stdClass();
    $oRefineByDefinition->sId = 1203;
    $oRefineByDefinition->sName = '';
    $oRefineBy->oRefineByDefinition = $oRefineByDefinition;

    $aParams7 = array(
            "sQuery"        =>     "jeans",
            "bAdult"        =>  0,
            "iOffset"       =>  0,
            "iLimit"        =>  30,
            "oActiveRefineByGroup"  =>  $oRefineBy,
            "sColumnToReturn"   =>  array("sDescription","sBrand"));

   // print '<pre>';print_r($aParams7); die;

    $products = $this->client->getProductList($aParams7);

    print_r($products);
}
```

I've tried adding it to the `'$aParams'` array but this doesn't work.

Comment: Is the element _UserAuthentication_ bound to some action in WSDL? Maybe you should make an additional login request before calling other methods? I see that in SOAP headers you are sending just an API key, so I guess the login part belongs to some method that you should call right after setting those headers... And why do you do this assignment: `$oRefineBy... = $oRefineByDefinition`? Doesn't it give you a warning or notice?

Comment: `iId` is a required parameter (your request object must have this property / array have this key)

Comment: @ponch Apologies for the late response. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @PiotrHorzycki That line was from the API documentation. I simply copied it from there.

Comment: It's all academic now guys anyway since I failed with the original assignment. If I can pick up some tips along the way though, it's always useful.