# SOAP fault code

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am having trouble with SOAP. When I try to send my request the server gives me back this error :

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns3:Server] Transaction aborted in /var/www/wing/ozk/MTPLPolicyIssue.php:258`

And on this line all I have is :

```
    $msg = $client->someFunction($message);
```

I would be gratefull to everyone who can tell me what does this error means and what is causing it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096638/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-ns1client-auth-1-authentication-fa) will definately help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but my authentication procedure is via PEM certificate and it is fine.