# XML to PHP SOAP request

Tags: php, xml, soap

A SOAP request XML looks like the following:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<net:GetAvailability>
    <net:request>
        <inh:UserCredentials>
           <inh:AgentID>**</inh:AgentID><inh:Password>**</inh:Password>
           <inh:Username>**</inh:Username>
        </inh:UserCredentials>

        <net:AccessCircuit>
            <arr:string>All</arr:string>
        </net:AccessCircuit>

        <net:RequestDetails xsi:type="net:TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <net:PerformMPFACCheck>No</net:PerformMPFACCheck>
            <net:ProxyCLI>true</net:ProxyCLI>
            <net:TelephoneNumber>0121****</net:TelephoneNumber>
        </net:RequestDetails>
        <net:UserConsent>Yes</net:UserConsent>
    </net:request>
</net:GetAvailability>
</soapenv:Body>
```

What I need to do is send this XML request using PHP SOAP however im not able to get this working. My current code is as follows:

```
$APIParameters = array(
        'request' => array(
            'UserCredentials' => array(
                'Username' => $this->apiUsername,
                'Password' => $this->apiPassword,
                'AgentID' => $this->apiResellerID,
            ),
            'AccessCircuit' => array(
                'string' => 'All'
            ),
            'UserConsent' => 'Yes',

        )
    );

    $APIParameters['request']['RequestDetails'] = new SoapParam( array('PerformMPFACCheck' => 'Yes', 'Postcode' => "****", 'ProxyCLI' => "true", 'TelephoneNumber' => '****'), "TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest");

    print_r($APIParameters);                        
    $apiResult = $SOAPClient->GetAvailability($APIParameters);
```

The print_r() returns the following:

```
Array
(
[request] => Array
    (
        [UserCredentials] => Array
            (
                [Username] => ****
                [Password] => ****
                [AgentID] => ****
            )

        [AccessCircuit] => Array
            (
                [string] => All
            )

        [UserConsent] => Yes
        [RequestDetails] => SoapParam Object
            (
                [param_name] => TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest
                [param_data] => Array
                    (
                        [PerformMPFACCheck] => Yes
                        [Postcode] => ****
                        [ProxyCLI] => true
                        [TelephoneNumber] => 0121****
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Yet the SOAP request fails with a Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault]. What am I doing wrong?! Appreciate any help!

Comment: You're probably going to have to ask the guy who maintains the soap service. You're sending something that's causing an uncaught exception. None of us can guess what it is.

Answer (score 0):

first check that your wsld soap access granted using this code

```
 <?php
// enter your url
    $client = new SoapClient('enteryoururl');
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```

then check which function have in this url if you have access and your function list show your function then try this

[Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns1:Client.AUTH_1] Authentication Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096638/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-ns1client-auth-1-authentication-fa)